# SELECT value from a second level foreign key table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, join

Greetings fellow Earthlings,

I have a problem. Let me start by laying out my table structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE Person
    (
        id varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        adress varchar(50) NOT NULL references Adress(id)
    )

    CREATE TABLE Adress
    (
        id varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        addressName varchar(50),
        city varchar(50),
        aState varchar(50),
        linkToCountry varchar(50) references Country(id)
    )

    CREATE TABLE Country
    (
        id varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        countryName varchar(50)
    )
```

What I want to achieve is: select a person 'name' along with their 'addressName' and the 'countryName' they're from. 
I know that this is a joining related issue but I can't seem to figure this one out.

So any help from people who are well versed on SQL?

Would appreciate it very very much any one has links to advance sql joining so I can familiarize myself with it.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds impolite, but ... you already know this is about joins and you don't know how to solve this??? This is the very, very basic inner join. About the first thing you learn at all. Have you even started trying to solve this yourself?

Comment: Yes I have. My knowledge of SQL is very elementary. So yes your comment does come of as impolite. I asked because I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: But you admit that the solution is very simple, don't you ? :-) Next time you should show the query you tried, so we see your effort and can even comment on it.

Comment: Will do so @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.name, a.addressName, c.countryName
FROM Person p 
INNER JOIN Adress a ON p.adress = a.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Country c ON a.linkToCountry = c.id
```

Comment: You can inner join table Adress. Person.adress is not nullable.

Comment: So now it's two inner joins instead of two outer joins :-) The left join on table Country actually made sense, because Adress.linkToCountry is nullable. @TheComplexOne: The difference would be that you would still get the result, even when the address contains no country (c.countryName would be null then).

Answer (score 2):

You can get the result using simple join as below. This will retrun the person name with address name, and country name. However it returns only those person names which has an address record in the address table and country record in the country table. If you want to retrieve all the persons irrespective of whether address/country exists or not, you need to use left join.

```
SELECT Person.Name, Address.addressname,Country.countryName
FROM Person 
     JOIN Address on Person.address = Address.Id
     JOIN Country ON Address.linkToCountry = Country.id
```